# Send message using content of a editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sendmessage

I'm trying to send a message from my app using as SMS content the content of a editText. I tryed in this way so far:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
String content = edit.getText().toString();
it.putExtra("sms_body", content);   
startActivity(it);
```

but when the activity starts there is no content in the message.. isn't possible do something like that?

Comment: The code you have posted is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send message like this

```
String phoneNo = "080000123";
String sms = textsms.getText().toString();
            try 
            {
                android.telephony.SmsManager smsmanager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsmanager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the same code of yours, but within a method call. This is because if you have more than 1 messaging app installed on your device you will have to manually select the app that you are going to send your message with.
In my case I have whatsapp, messaging, etc. So having your code in the onCreate(), it will only fail as there is no option selected by the user...But when I have this code within a method body and I trigger with a button or any other even similarly, it works fine(only thing is you will have to select the app-you can make any of the app as default so that the next time you don't have to do this manually).

My MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void send(View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:9999999999");
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String content = edit.getText().toString();
        it.putExtra("sms_body", content);
        startActivity(it);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="send" />

</LinearLayout>
```